# Getting time difference in seconds

Tags: php, wordpress, date, time

I created a custom form on a WordPress website that lets users click a button to start recording time, and then later on another page there is a different form that lets the user stop recording time.

When they submit the first form to start recording time, I add this post meta to the database:

```
/* Start timer */
$now = strtotime('now');
update_post_meta( $post_id, 'start_time', $now);
```

An example value in the database is something like this: **1627607870**

When they submit the second form later to stop recording time, I add this post meta to the database:

```
/* End timer */
$now = strtotime('now');
update_post_meta( $post_id, 'end_time', $now);
```

An example value in the database is something like this: **1627607890**

To calculate how much time had passed, I do simple subtraction:

```
/* Total time */
$start_time     = get_post_meta($post_id, 'start_time', TRUE);
$end_time       = get_post_meta($post_id, 'end_time', TRUE);
$total_time     = $end_time - $start_time;
echo $total_time;
```

...which, using the example values shown above `$total_time` would return **20**.

This all works fine - for me. But, I have some users in different countries who say that the total time returned is completely wrong, sometimes even showing what appears to be long completely random numbers.

So I am wondering if there something wrong with my approach? My gut feeling is that different timezones could affect `$total_time` but I might be wrong.

Comment: Have a look at the [php manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php): *Warning
The Unix timestamp that this function returns does not contain information about time zones. In order to do calculations with date/time information, you should use the more capable DateTimeImmutable.*

Comment: I saw that but I'm not convinced it matters, but maybe there's something I don't understand about this. The way I see it, the values of $now, $start_time and $end_time are established by getting the number of seconds since the 0:00:00 January 1,1970 GMT.

Comment: That's right, unix timestamps usually don't contain timezone information. I'm not sure what's going on there

Answer (score 0):

You could try calculating time from GMT. this way, you can atleast get assured if it is a timezone issue or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function **current_time(timestamp);** it brings the time zone set in the WP admin.

The WordPress has some Constants to work with time:

```
MINUTE_IN_SECONDS 

HOUR_IN_SECONDS 

DAY_IN_SECONDS 

WEEK_IN_SECONDS

MONTH_IN_SECONDS 

YEAR_IN_SECONDS
```

Answer (score 0):

Another WordPress Function of time duration is **human_readable_duration()**

Convert a duration to human readable format.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/human_readable_duration/